# Kotlin Native iOS string formatting with vararg

Tags: objective-c, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/1834) about using `NSString` formatting I try to implement multiplatform implementation for formatting when using `vararg`, with no luck so far.

What I did

- added FoundationInterop.def

```
language = Objective-C
---
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>

NSString* format(NSString* format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

- compiled it in gradle

```
targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos")  \
         ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

        // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-dsl-reference.html#native-targets
        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'ios') {
            binaries {
            }

            compilations.main.cinterops {
                FoundationInterop {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- Created `StringExtensions.kt` in `commonMain`

```
expect class StringType

expect fun String.format(format: String, vararg args: Any?): StringType?
```

- in `iosMain`

```
actual typealias StringType = String

/**
 * https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/1834
 */
actual fun String.format(format: String, vararg args: Any?): StringType? {
    return FoundationInterop.format(format, args as Any)
}
```

- example

```
val fmt = "http://geomag.bgs.ac.uk/web_service/GMModels/igrf/13/?latitude=%f&longitude=%f&altitude=0&date=%d-%02d-%02d&format=json"
val url = fmt.format(urlFmt, 59.127934932762166, 38.00503518930868, 2020, 1, 3)
```

- output - **as you see no values substitutions occured for some reason**

```
http://geomag.bgs.ac.uk/web_service/GMModels/igrf/13/?latitude=0.000000&longitude=0.000000&altitude=0&date=43344272-198763328-00&format=json
```

**Edit**

`stringWithFormat` gives the same result

```
actual fun String.format(format: String, vararg args: Any?): StringType? {
    return NSString.stringWithFormat(format, args as Any)
}
```

**Edit 2**

Created issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42925

Comment: Not an answer to your question that I would like to check why it doesn't work, but the issue you provided is now closed: *Starting from 1.3.40, it will be possible to use `initWithFormat` directly*.

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks for pointing this out, but it does not work either, see my edit

Comment: @shadowsheep this method works when we pass params like `NSString.stringWithFormat("%@ %@ %d", "один" as NSString, "two" as NSString, 3)` but not with `vararg`

Comment: Got it. Now it's more clear ;). So I could suggest to "format" your format and you vararg so that the function work accordingly, inside iOS actual fun.

Comment: @shadowsheep how would it look like?

Comment: As soon as I've time to check I'll show you, if someone else don't do it before ;)

Comment: Hello @schmidt9. How do you implement "expect fun String.format .... " on AndroidMain module?

Comment: @Arubu I did iOS implementation only, Android part is not my responsibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm what you say about `NSString.stringWithFormat`. The feature is missing as we read in the JB offical answer from
Svyatoslav Scherbina and we could follow the issue from you here: [KT-42925](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42925)

As an awful workaround, I was suggesting something like that (**WARNING**: not exhaustive, without many index count checks...)

```kotlin
import platform.Foundation.NSString
import platform.Foundation.stringWithFormat

actual typealias StringType = String

actual fun String.format(format: String, vararg args: Any?): StringType? {
    var returnString = ""
    val regEx = "%[\\d|.]*[sdf]|[%]".toRegex()
    val singleFormats = regEx.findAll(format).map {
        it.groupValues.first()
    }.asSequence().toList()
    val newStrings = format.split(regEx)
    for (i in 0 until args.count()) {
        val arg = args[i]
        returnString += when (arg) {
            is Double -> {
                NSString.stringWithFormat(newStrings[i] + singleFormats[i], args[i] as Double)
            }
            is Int -> {
                NSString.stringWithFormat(newStrings[i] + singleFormats[i], args[i] as Int)
            }
            else -> {
                NSString.stringWithFormat(newStrings[i] + "%@", args[i])
            }
        }
    }

    return returnString
}
```

But look if it could be a valid workaround for you.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is an interesting workaround, I'll wait a while maybe other solution will come, if not, I'll except your answer, it's a pain that we should reinvent wheels in Kotlin Native to do such basic things. BTW maybe you know some KN libraries that already have multiplatform strings formatting options?

Comment: That's the fee to pay for playing with a bleeding edge technology. Think that we are in alpha stage and only fiew things are in beta. I don't know if there are already KN libs dealing with strings formatting, but you can start searching [here](https://libs.kmp.icerock.dev/) and [here](https://www.kotlinresources.com/). You could also join the kotlin slack channel and ask in the #multiplatform chamber.

Comment: here we have official answer, maybe it would be interesting for you too

Comment: Yup! I've seen. That's what we discovered too. The feature is missing and we made the workaround. W8ing for this feature to be added ;). Btw I've already upvoted your answer. And if you like to change the accepted answer feel free to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't forward Kotlin variadic arguments to C or Objective-C. C variadics are compile time.
It is not a Kotlin-specific limitation. You can't call a variadic C function from another variadic C function with forwarding all the arguments.

> NSString.stringWithFormat(format, args as Any)

This is not correct.
This line takes `args` (which is an `Array`), casts it to `Any` and passes as a single argument.

So this is mostly equivalent to something like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:format, createKotlinArray(/* all arguments here */)]
```

which doesn't do what you expect.

So [KT-42925](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42925) is not valid.
Your problem could possibly be solved by one of the missing features:

- Common `String.format` in stdlib ([KT-25506](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25506)). But this is not easy.
- Support for building `va_list` dynamically, e.g. from Kotlin `Array` ([KT-42973](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42973)). In this case it would be easy to use this variant: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407827-initwithformat